# How can I end a .switchClass event on mouseout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am currently working on a site that has a main billboard on the top of the page. And on that billboard is 6 thumbnails off the right that are used to switch what div is being displayed in the billboard. It looks something like this:

[image]

When you hover over the thumbnails, they extend out to the left to display some text like this:

[image]

The problem I am having is: If the user moves the mouse out of the div before the .switchClass animation is finished for the .hover mouse-in handler, then the .switchClass event in the mouse-out handler either fires too early, or not at all, resulting in the hover effect remaining even after the user has moved the mouse out. Essentially leaving the thumbnail "open" like the in the above picture.

Is there a way to interrupt the mouse-in .switchClass animation when the user mouse-out?

My code is as follows:

HTML:

```
                <div id="bbTab1" class ="inactive" style="margin-top:30px">
                    <div class="rightBorder"></div>
                    <img class="tabImage" src="images/bbtab1.png" />
                    <div class="leftBorder"></div>
                </div><!--bbTab1-->

                <div id="bbTab2" class ="inactive" style="margin-top:95px">
                    <div class="rightBorder"></div>
                    <img class="tabImage" src="images/bbtab2.png" />
                    <div class="leftBorder"></div>
                </div><!--bbTab2-->

                <div id="bbTab3" class ="inactive" style="margin-top:160px">
                    <div class="rightBorder"></div>
                    <img class="tabImage" src="images/bbtab3.png" />
                    <div class="leftBorder"></div>
                </div><!--bbTab3-->

                <div id="bbTab4" class ="inactive" style="margin-top:225px">
                    <div class="rightBorder"></div>
                    <img class="tabImage" src="images/bbtab4.png" />
                    <div class="leftBorder"></div>
                </div><!--bbTab4-->

                <div id="bbTab5" class ="inactive" style="margin-top:290px">
                    <div class="rightBorder"></div>
                    <img class="tabImage" src="images/bbtab5.png" />
                    <span class="bText"> This is some text </span>
                    <div class="leftBorder"></div>
                </div><!--bbTab5-->

                <div id="bbTab6" class="inactive" style="margin-top:355px">
                    <div class="rightBorder"></div>
                    <img class="tabImage" src="images/bbtab6.png" />
                    <div class="leftBorder"></div>
                </div><!--bbTab6-->
```

CSS:

```
    #billboard .inactive{
    width:53px;
    height:57px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ACACAC;
    border-top: 1px solid #ACACAC;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5000;
    right:0;
}
#billboard .inactiveHover{
    width:180px; /*61px*/
    height:57px;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF9B15;
    border-top: 1px solid #FF9B15;
    z-index:5000;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}   
#billboard .active{
    width:61px; /*61px*/
    height:57px;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF9B15;
    border-top: 1px solid #FF9B15;
    z-index:5000;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

JS: Using Jquery 1.8.2 and Jquery UI 1.9.1

```
$(function() {
$(".inactive").hover(
    function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("active")){return;}
        else{$(this).switchClass("inactive", "inactiveHover", 300, "easeOutQuint");}
    },
    function () {
        if($(this).hasClass("active")){
            $(this).removeClass("inactive").removeClass("inactiveHover");   
        }
        else{$(this).switchClass("inactiveHover", "inactive", 300, "easeOutQuint");}                    
}); 
});
```

Comment: If you remove `if($(this).hasClass("inactiveHover")){` won't that fix it?

Comment: I thought about that and removed it to see the effect, but to no avail. The reason that line is there is because if you actually click on the thumbnail the class becomes "active", and "active" classes have no hover effects. I edited the function in the post to the most recent and best working, still having the same issue though.

Comment: Could CSS transitions work for you? What browsers do you have to support? Is this the sort of effect you want to produce (but in JavaScript)? http://jsfiddle.net/mhNzH/

Comment: With your new code I can not seem to get the div to stick on the hover position, so that seems to be fixed.  What is it about your current code that you do not like?

Comment: @Greg The CSS transitions are working really well. I still have one problem though. The text inside the thumbnail awkwardly animates into place. (it kind of slides under the thumbnail and pulls up into place when there is enough room for it) is there anyway to fix this? Either have the text display when the extend is complete or to have the text almost "appear" as the div extends left?

Comment: @Greg I was also wondering how I can change the value of "width" for the .tab:hover element based on what div I am currently hovering over, because not all of the thumbnails will have the same "extend" width. I know I could give each thumbnail div an ID and created a separate CSS rule for each of the different divs, but I was hoping for a little cleaner solution.

Comment: @Rob_IGS you could use opacity, and fade the text in once the previous animation is complete http://jsfiddle.net/mhNzH/4/ as for the automatic width you'll want to calculate that using JS. Setting width to auto won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you should be using the [`.stop()` event](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

In essence, in both the mouse in and mouse out events, do `$(this).stop(true, true)` to interrupt the animation and to jump to the final result of the animation.

Or if you want to have it just stop and not jump to the final animation, do `$(this).stop(true, false)`

Comment: The problem with `.stop(true, false)` is that the new class does not get assigned if the animation does not finish, but you are right `.stop(true, true)` should help.

Comment: Your both right, I used $(this).stop(true,true).switchClass("inactiveHover", "inactive") so that I stop the previous animation (extending out) and start the new animation (retracting back in).